# Laravel eloquent distinct select with possibility to call relation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relational-database

I want to select distinct results from one table, the structure is following:

```
id, user_id, category_id, last_answered_question_id
```

I have relation for `last_answered_question_id` called: `lastAnsweredQuestion()`

My query is:

```
Answer::select('category_id')->where(['user_id' => $userId])->distinct()->get();
```

This query works as expected but in this case I can't call relation `$answer = lastAnsweredQuestion`.

Is there any known way to get distinct items and call relation `lastAnsweredQuestion()` anyway?

Comment: There can be multiple values from `last_answered_question_id` for a category ? In this case do you need all `last_answered_question_id`s or is there any criteria to pick one ?

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple and I need only last one.